# What does (Class*)(0) mean in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have come across some code along the lines of below:

```
if(instance != (Class*)(0))
```

Could someone describe what this is doing?

Comment: You have `Class` in subject, but `class` in question body. The case can make a world of difference, as `class` is a keyword, but `Class` isn't.

Comment: here you go: error: expected primary-expression before 'class'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It short: it tests if pointer is null or not.

In detail: The expression `(Class*)(0)` is actually performing a typecast from 0 (i.e. `NULL`) to a pointer of type `Class`, it then compares this pointer (which is a constant NULL) to the **pointer** variable `instance`.

An example:

```
void Check(YourClass *instance)
{
   if(instance != (YourClass*)(0))
      // do this
}
```

Now the imporatant question is **why**. Why not simply as:

```
 if(instance != 0)
      // do this
```

Well, it is just for code-portability. Some compilers may raise warning that `Class*` is being compared with `int` (since `NULL` is nothing but `0`, which is `int`). Many static-analysis tool may also complain for simple NULL check with a class-type pointer.

Comment: How is it being compared to `int *`? It's compared to `int`.

Comment: `0` has type **int** in some contexts, but never **int***. When it is used a null pointer constant, it has some special type (not **void*** either) that can convert to/compare with any pointer type.

Comment: Thanks, I guess for my uses the second example there will be ample!

Comment: Of course, any tool that complains about well-defined, unambiguous usages should be taken out and shot.

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether `instance` doesn't point to address `0`, the cast to `Class*` is redundant.

If `instance` is an object, it calls `bool operator != (const Class*) const`;

Comment: @LuchianGrigore In C or in C++ mode?

Comment: @hvd C++, as the tag says. Why shouldn't it compile?

Comment: `class` is a keyword, not a type name

Comment: :) okay, the code clearly isn't the actual code, guess I was just reading between the lines (he says `Class` in the title and `class` in the q)

Comment: may as well move my comment down here.  shouldn't build. class is a keyword! :p

Comment: by the way, there is probably a reason why that person wrote (Class*)0 instead of just 0.  why?  :p

Comment: Hmm. You've actually edited your answer completely, my original comment doeesn't apply at all.

Answer (score 1):

If `instance` is a pointer, this checks whether it is `NULL`. The cast is redundant.

If `instance` is something other than a pointer (e.g. an instance of some class), the semantics depend on the class because operator overloading enters the picture.

Comment: Only if `instance` points to `Class`. Otherwise a comparison with 0 casted to `Class *` results with an error (at least with gcc).

Comment: @dragonroot, you mean "0 casted to Class*"?

Comment: @thang: yes. Fixed the original comment.

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether the pointer you're comparing it to points to `NULL`. The `(Class *)` cast is unnecessary. It is equivalent to the following in C++0x:

```
if (instance != nullptr)
```

Assuming that instance is a pointer, which it most certainly is.

Comment: Please use `C++11` instead of `C++0x`.